# apex inputText value null in controller

Tags: salesforce, visualforce, apex

I have an input filed that I am attempting to pass the end user's entered input into the SF controller class.

Below is the inputText visualforce code:

```
<div class="ssa-inputs">
  <div class="ssa-input-text">Name: </div>
    <div class="ssa-input">
      <apex:form>
        <apex:inputText value="{!acknowledgeInput}" id="acknowledgeInput"/>
      </apex:form>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="ssa-btns">
    <div class="ssa-btn">
      <apex:form>
        <apex:commandButton id="acceptHidden" value="Accept" action="{!updatecontact}"/>
      </apex:form>
      <input type="submit" id="acceptBtn" value="Accept"/>
    </div>
    <div class="ssa-btn">
      <apex:form>
        <apex:commandButton value="Decline" action="{!updatecontact}"/>
      </apex:form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Below is the SF controller code:

```
public string acknowledgeInput{get;set;}

public PageReference updatecontact(){
    System.debug(LoggingLevel.DEBUG, acknowledgeInput); 

    // Update contact information
    // Redirect to respected PageReference
}
```

When I try to print out the value in the logs, I receive null.

I feel like this is pretty straight forward and I can't seem to find what I'm missing.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to have the command button and input text field in the same form.